# Disable Deep Sleep on Brother MFC-J4620DW LAN

Tags: printer, sleep

So I've got a Brother printer that's plugged in over LAN, but the issue is that it keeps going into this "Deep Sleep" mode to try to save energy.  However, when it's in deep sleep, it cannot be woken by wireless devices that want to print, such as other computers.

Honestly, this interferes with productivity so much that, at this point, I don't care about saving energy.  I want to be able to disable Deep Sleep so that I can print wirelessly, like a printer was designed to do...

Answer (score 0):

#### I want to be able to disable Deep Sleep

> To cancel DEEP SLEEP on Brother Printer
>
> 1. Go to General Setup then OK
> 2. Ecology then OK
> 3. SLEEP TIME then OK
> 4. While sleep time is display push Down Arrow and CANCEL **or** push Job Cancel and Start at the same time
> 5. DEEP SLEEP on/off toggle by Arrow keys
> 6. OK to SAVE Deep Sleep off.

Source [Brother 4150 CDN “Deep Sleep” How do I disable?](https://serverfault.com/questions/416422/brother-4150-cdn-deep-sleep-how-do-i-disable), answers by [tony Benjamin](https://serverfault.com/users/214041/tony-benjamin) and [Edward D. Baum](https://serverfault.com/users/226750/edward-d-baum)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried this, but this is for a completely different printer than the one I've got.